# How To Save Dynamic Pivot Variable Output As SQL Server Table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, variables, pivot

I have successfully constructed the output that I have been looking for from using dynamic SQL to create a pivot table with dynamically created column names.

My code is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempDB') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempDB
SELECT CASEID, FORMNAME, NAME, VALUE INTO #TempDB FROM dbo.EFORM WHERE FORMNAME='IncidentReporting'

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempDB1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempDB1
SELECT DISTINCT Name INTO #TempDB1 FROM #TempDB

DECLARE @columns varchar(max)
DECLARE @query varchar(max)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast([Name] as varchar(100)) + ']', 
             '[' + cast([Name] as varchar(100))+ ']') 
             FROM #TempDB1

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM #TempDB AS PivotData '
SET @query = @query  + 
'PIVOT (MAX(VALUE) FOR [NAME] IN (' + @columns + ')) AS p'

EXEC (@query)
```

This successfully gives me results like:

```
CASEID  FORMNAME             Column1    Column2 Column3
501000000621    IncidentReporting   Value1  Valuea  Valuev
501000000622    IncidentReporting   Value2  Valueb  Valuew
601000000126    IncidentReporting   Value3  Valuec  Valuex
601000000127    IncidentReporting   Value4  Valued  Valuey
601000000128    IncidentReporting   Value5  Valuee  Valuez
```

These results, outputed from the @query variable, are in exactly the format that I want a table of these results to be in.

Can anyone tell me how to get the results that are in the @query variable into a standard SQL table?

I have tried doing a statement like this, but I get the message "Incorrect syntax near ' + @columns + '":

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempDB4
FROM (SELECT * FROM #TempDB AS PivotData 
PIVOT (MAX(VALUE) FOR [NAME] IN (' + @columns + ')) AS p)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your existing code, add your `into` to this line:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM #TempDB AS PivotData '
```

so that you get:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT * INTO #TempDB4 FROM #TempDB AS PivotData '
```

Or add `insert` in the same manner.

To get your unsuccessful query to work as you expect, you'd have to turn that into dynamic SQL, much like your successful query, and call it using `exec` or `sp_executesql`

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  You have no idea how much Googling failed to come up with this simple solution.  Works perfectly!

Comment: In order for this to work, you need to make it a global temp variable. ##temp